# How to test if a Set contains at least one value in another set

Tags: scala, set

**Given** a `Set` a with a size a

**And** a `Set` b with a size b

What is the most performant solution to test if b contains at least one value in a.

Solution 1 : What is the complexity of intersect ?

```
def containsAtLeastOne[A](a:Set[A], b: Set[A]) = a.intersect(b).nonEmpty
```

Solution 2 : O(a) in worst case

```
def containsAtLeastOne[A](a:Set[A], b: Set[A]) = a.exists(b.contains(_))
```

Solution 3 : O(b) in worst case

```
def containsAtLeastOne[A](a:Set[A], b: Set[A]) = b.exists(a.contains(_))
```

Comment: The best way to answer this is to benchmark. Solutions 2 and 3 also have a lambda dispatch while Solution 1 is pure JVM calls.

Comment: All of your solutions are `O(ab)`, probably no real perf difference except for the lambda in 2/3.

Comment: Is an edit needed here?  Solutions 2 and 3 are the same.

Comment: `intersect` for `immutable.TreeSet` is simply `a filter b`, thus it's *O(a log b)*, the same as the other two methods. But for two `immutable.HashSet`s `intersect` is more complex using data about their internal structures (bitmasks, etc.), so it might actually be considerably faster, than the other two.

Comment: @noah are you sure ? contains in a `Set` seems to be O(1) cf http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html

Comment: @YannMoisan yes you're correct, there's a `HashSet` behind the scenes, so in theory it should amortize to O(1).

Answer (score 4):

Solution 2 and 3 are faster compared to 1st solution.

But which is faster out of solution 2 and solution 3?

This depends on data that each set contains.
For example imagine that setA has 100 elements and setB has 3 elements and last element in setA is only common element in these two sets. In this case 3rd solution is faster. So this just not depends on set size but the data that set contains as well.

Anyway you should always prefer 2nd and 3rd solution if need more optimized, you can call exists method on smaller set, it should be faster in most of the cases.